# Reading php-encoded JSON in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have created a JSON object in php using json_encode and am attempting to display certain values of that object in javascipt through AJAX. I have no issue receiving the response from php but am getting 'undefined' when I try to access any value of the response using JSON notation.

**Code snippet:**

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
   alert(response);
   alert(response.data);
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"data":[{"cheese":"pork"},{"cheese":"chicken"}]} // Yes, I'm hungry right now.
undefined
```

**EDIT: Thanks everybody for the responses. Wish I could give you all a check mark but I have selected the most helpful response.**

Comment: You need to parse that JSON back into JavaScript objects see [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) {or if you're desperate use `eval`, but there's security risks of this}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the json. This can be done through a simple call to `eval`, but this can only be done if you absolutely trust the returning server as he can make your script execute everything.

```
 var data = eval('('+response+')');
```

The way I would recommand if to use `json2.js`, a small javascript library that ius faster and will handle the parsing for you.

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

It can be acquire from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   var jdoc = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   alert(jdoc.data[0].cheese);
}
```

Include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in older browsers.

Comment: Please tell me if there is an error in the code I'm writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert response into js object.

The simpliest way is to use eval():

```
eval('var result = ' +response);
alert(result.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText
```

this is not a JSON object. This is plain text.
Use `var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');` for example to get JSON (eval is evil:)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like response is plain text. 
Try this:

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
var data = new Function("return "+xmlhttp.responseText)();
```